# Useful alternative to MCVE links and the standard boilerplate comments

Tags: discussion

In this post, I want to share something I created and started using a few days ago because so far it seems to have had a fairly good reception. So, I thought, I'd share it here because I think that in some cases it can be more useful and **more effective** than the standard [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) links and standard boilerplate comments for posts with those issues.

For background: I joined SO just a few months ago and I still remember how extremely dumb I was when I posted my first questions (only posted 7 questions so far).

**I still vividly remember how I felt when trying to post my first questions as a clueless newbie and the desperation when my second, third and fourth question started getting hammered by downvotes** and I started seeing the warnings that soon (because of the downvotes) "I won't be able to post questions anymore".

And now, after having posted answers for 4 full weeks on SO (176 answers so far and probably somewhere around 300-400 comments) I am in a rare situation where I currently still have an insight into both worlds. On the one hand, I still vividly remember my actions and feelings as a clueless newbie, on the other hand, I'm currently ranking as one of the top answerers of a certain tag I'm focusing on.

Based on that, here's the boilerplate comment I designed specifically for questions of newbies that don't post the necessary code or don't post a complete snippet that's required for answering their question:

```
If you expect any sensible answers, 
you need to post a **complete** code snippet 
(HTML, CSS & JavaScript including CDN links) 
that allows *replicating your issue exactly*. 
Otherwise, any answers would be based on guesswork 
and you want to avoid that. 
[Edit] your question and post your **complete** 
current code snippet there at the bottom 
by clicking the *"JavaScript/HTML/CSS snippet"* icon.
```

I'm posting that as a snippet there so you guys can easily copy the formatting if you want.

Note: This is tailored specifically to the types of questions I'm handling. So, if you are dealing with something like C++ or Java questions, then you obviously don't need HTML code.

Anyway, feel free to copy and adjust that boilerplate as needed.

### Here's why I think it's a good alternative to the standard MCVE links and standard boilerplate comments for those cases:

1. It starts with an immediate and clear benefit to the asker: **"If you expect any sensible answers..."** -- *"Oh, yes, of course, I expect and WANT sensible answers! Let me read further!..."* So, that's designed to get the user to read **and** follow instructions. As opposed to that, the standard MCVE links and standard boilerplate comments feel like an annoying chore that someone forces you to do. It's more effective to make the users **WANT** to do what they need to do.
2. The next part tells the users exactly WHAT they need to do (and it tells them that right there in the comment, no need to click a link!) and it tells them HOW they need to do it i.e. "your code must enable us to *replicate your issue exactly*".
3. The next part gives them another reason WHY and makes crystal clear (without being offensive) that the current state of their question is useless.
4. The final part gives them an **instant and VERY PRECISE step-by-step instruction**: "[Edit] your question and post your **complete** current code snippet there at the bottom by clicking the *"JavaScript/HTML/CSS snippet"* icon."

That step-by-step instruction is so clear and precise that even intellectually challenged users should be able to complete those steps:

- Edit your question (there is a link that literally says "edit"), helps preventing them from posting the code as a comment
- Post your code at the bottom of the question (not at the top)
- Make sure it's complete so we can replicate your issue
- Click that icon that says "JavaScript/HTML/CSS snippet" -- *"Aha! That's the right way for me to do that!"*

All that helpful information and precise instructions are conveyed in one fairly short comment without the need to click any links. Plus, it instantly **makes them WANT** to follow those instructions because it immediately gives them good, *selfish* reasons for that!

As opposed that (and this is based on my *personal*, still fresh experience as a newbie question poster) the standard MCVE links or other standard boilerplate comments that contain even more than one link (!) make me (as a question poster) feel like I'm being forced to *"read a manual"* which is the last thing I want to do when I'm trying to get answers to a burning question.

Long story short:

Feel free to copy, modify and use my comment template in any way you like.

If you are dealing with questions where you need that kind of code formatting (instead of HTML code), you might want to point out that you *first have to highlight all lines of code* and then click the code formatting button (or use the corresponding shortcut). (That little trick for formatting *multi-line* code was a big mystery to me until now)

I want to be clear that the comment template I shared here is not supposed to some kind of a "be all, end all" comment template.
I personally have about 2-3 of appropriate cases per day, and the  comment template is quite handy for those particular cases. For other cases, I use other templates.

---

I don't use any template when I have a case where none of my comment templates fits 100%. And that's what I recommend doing.

Feel free to create a few different templates that fit different recurring cases. But ONLY use those templates when they actually fit 100% and DON'T use templates in any other cases.

Comment: Posting canned comments... search for discussion of using idownvotedbecau.se for some insights.

Comment: Don't need to search for that. I saw those links and I DON'T think canned comments and those links, in particular, are as good as some people might believe them to be. That's precisely **because** they immediately appear to be canned and impersonal. My comment template, on the other hand, appears to be a personal comment written by a human being who cares and is trying to help them. Quite a difference...

Comment: Imho, the comment is missing the **minimal** part of MCVE. We don't want users to post hundreds of lines of HTML/Javascript/CSS just because thats there "current code snipped". They should first find out which part causes the problem and post only the necessary parts to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @BDL That's why you are supposed to customize it to your needs. In my cases, the "minimal" part is **never needed**! Never had a case where "too much code" was posted. Always the opposite in cases I'm dealing with.

Comment: @BDL So, the whole point of my comment template is to AVOID appearing to be canned and thus impersonal! To achieve that effect the comment **must NOT** include anything that's irrelevant to their particular case. As soon as you include an irrelevant part, it immediately appears canned and thus loses effectiveness. I actually want them to have a good opinion of me even AFTER I post that comment. The "idownvotedbecau.se" links (as an example) achieve the exact opposite!

Comment: @BoltClock I still haven't figured how to post multi-line code that way. I mean, I don't want to sit all day typing indentations for each line or clicking a button to insert each individual line of code. Is there a shortcut for formatting multi-line code that way? I bet there must be but it's very non-obvious.

Comment: You can select the lines of code you have and press `CTRL + K`.

Comment: @Justastudent I think you just saved my life! So, I'll get to live another day! :-)

Comment: Yay! May I suggest one minor change to your template? Maybe change `Edit` into `[Edit]`, so that it becomes a link: [Edit] your question ... :-)

Comment: @Justastudent Brilliant! THAT is definitely a link that's very useful and worth to include!

Comment: I agree in theory that canned remarks can be impersonal, but offering links to show people how to write decent questions is necessary, since there is a lot of information to take in. Given the numbers of people posting low-quality questions, we cannot write them all a personalised letter, and there's only so much hand-holding we can do before it does not scale.

Comment: @WebDevBooster Maybe in your corner of SO you've not come across intractable code dumps, but rest assured they exist and they're a problem.  When you're looking at a question with 3500 lines of code with missing dependencies and that doesn't compile with an OP who has provided no debug information and a "question" of *"It's crash when I frob the McGuffin... why?!  Help please, its due in an hour!1!"* you'll come to appreciate the need for the "minimal" part.

Comment: I don't accept that canned comments are an indicator of someone who is "inhuman" or "does not care" - if the link contains helpful information, then surely that is a helpful action? If the question author is positive and is willing to accept a useful critique, then they will do fine, as long as they improve their future questions and put in a good effort first. Indeed, often a poor question reception comes from a lack of effort, rather than not understanding the culture and guidelines here.

Comment: @halfer Sure! That's why I said, at the very beginning, that my template is an alternative for *some cases*, not all of them. It's designed to be an alternative for those cases where I actually would like to answer the question myself but can't do that without code. So, it's not a "be all, end all" template. It's just a template for those particular cases.

Comment: Fair enough, sure. I'd add that I would suspect the number of community-minded volunteers (commenters, editors, thoughtful voters) is miniscule compared to the vast number of lazy drive-bys who want an answer to their poorly-stated problem yesterday. I am certainly on the "be nice" side of the argument, but of course part of the respect that we are all due is that effort should go into questions. One good bit of advice I saw in a comment was "pretend you're talking to a busy colleague" (i.e. make your question succinct and prepare the useful information I need in advance).

Comment: Do you think **bolding** all important items is **enough** indication to **ensure** that people **will** actually read and act upon it?

Comment: @usr2564301 No. But I think that starting the comment with something like *"If you expect any sensible answers..."* does that.

Comment: I think the point was that the template should dispense with all formatting in that case. Otherwise it just makes the comment even more annoying to read and even less likely to be heeded, thus defeating the carefully crafted language.

Comment: @BoltClock Respect your opinion but disagree in this case. The particular formatting I use for that comment was very carefully chosen/designed by me to increase effectiveness BUT you don't have to agree with that. You can think of it as my personal preference/style. No one has to use that formatting. Change it in any way you like.

Comment: @JoshCaswell I don't like when my posts are edited for no reason. I put a lot of thought into my formatting. Don't touch it.

Comment: You used code formatting [for stuff that's not code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254990/when-should-code-formatting-be-used-for-non-code-text); that's not no reason.

Comment: [Can I prevent others from editing my question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/28005)

Comment: @JoshCaswell I used code formatting to highlight things the way I want them to highlight. That's my deliberate choice. Don't mess with that!

Comment: Yeah, uh, that's not how this works.

Comment: @JoshCaswell Yes! That's how it works! You don't need to look after MY formatting. Look after yours. That should suffice.

Comment: Not all questions are debugging questions. What would be better is if people stopped requesting mcve's from questions that do not require them. Dont copy and paste comments, tell the author exactly what is needed to answer the damn question so it can be answered. If you dont know exactly what is necessary to answer then keep your comments to yourself. Stop beating around the bush and tell the person what you want.

Comment: @TinyGiant If a question doesn't require an MCVE, then requesting it would be a very bad idea indeed. I agree. That's one of the reasons why I designed my comment template in such way that it tells the user to do only and precisely those things that are required to answer their question and no more. (I don't need them to read the MCVE page if they just do what I tell them to do in that comment)

Comment: The better option would be to not use template comments, and instead tell the user exactly what is required to answer the specific question. General advice is generally not all that useful in specific cases, and can also be frustrating and annoying for the receiver. it isnt hard to formulate 500 characters.

Comment: Also your singular focus on the code sample being complete misses the point that we also want it to be minimal and generalized. (The M part of MCVE)

Comment: @TinyGiant My template has been designed precisely to **tell the user exactly what is required to answer their specific question** for a significant number of questions I see every day. I use different templates for different cases and only if they fit. You don't seem to have ever seen those situations. So, it's difficult for you to wrap your head around the fact that those cases do exist and occur quite frequently in some areas. Just move on in this case. No one forces you to use that temple. I just wanted to share it because some people might also find it useful for some of their cases.

Comment: @TinyGiant I don't need nor want the code to be "minimal and generalized" in MY cases because I never had problems with that in MY cases. (hope you get it this time)

Comment: Trust me, I have seen a great many situations and I have seen that the use of such templates and knee-jerk reactions to posts with little actual effort put into evaluating the question (as is often the case with pro-forma comments) are detrimental to the site, and are much less useful than the posters think they are. I am opposed to anyone using such comments because they are annoying and are rarely neccessary when used or useful when neccessary. I **don't** want people using your template because it is a bad idea.

Comment: My point being that you may think you're being helpful by copying and pasting comments en-masse all over the site, but it really just shows a lack of effort on your part. I don't think template comments should ever be used, and if people are going to write comments, they should put some effort into it.

Comment: @TinyGiant You are discussing some theoretical stuff that does NOT apply to MY cases in practice. Go read some other posts, there's no shortage of that!

Comment: No, contrary to what your suggesting in this post I am actually discussing this post. That you do not like what I'm writing does not make it inapplicable.

Comment: @TinyGiant I'm sure it's applicable to you 100%. Absolutely to doubt about that!

Comment: So far you have done nothing but dismiss every criticism you have received from multiple users in this comment thread. You obviously have no respect for the community. Maybe you could learn from the criticisms instead, that would be much more useful but im sure its not "applicable to you 100%" because you're special right?

Comment: I appreciate this post. I just wanted to agree that people asking questions are humans who are busy and intelligent, just like people answering. I think usually they're just looking for a human to give a problem genuine attention. Couldn't answerers be just as guilty of wanting things to be quick and easy for them? Is answerer time more valuable than questioner time? Or is this a community, where an _answerer willing to take time_ and a questioner can find one another and solve stuff? I feel like the specific, instructive comments mentioned serve that end, contempt of questioners not so much.

Answer (score 8):

Golly, this reminds me of my early days on this site when I would continually type out similar comments to folks, time after time after time. I eventually went back in and searched my comments for these guys and collated them. Here for your reading pleasure are some of my "masterpieces":

> Consider posting a minimal code example that demonstrates your problem, an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org). This will allow us to run your code and modify it and perhaps even correct it.  Please read the link before replying as it supplies many important details on the SSCCE requirements.

> Your best bet here is not to show your whole program, but to condense your question/problem into a single small class that is compilable by any and all of us, and demonstrates your problem.  In other words, a  [Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example or SSCCE](http://sscce.org). Remember, the code should be compilable and runnable for many of us to be able to understand it fully.

> Your best bet here is to show us your code. We don't want to see all of it, but rather you should condense your code into the smallest bit that still compiles, has no extra code that's not relevant to your problem, but still demonstrates your problem, in other words, an SSCCE (Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example). For more info on SSCCEs please look here: [SSCCE](http://sscce.org)

> I suggest that you first of all try to do this sort of thing in a very simple and very small program that does nothing but shows us your problem and doesn't have all of the other unrelated components and code. This will make it much easier for us to understand and help you fix. Then if you're still having a problem, post this small compilable and runnable program. Some call this process of simplification "creating an [sscce](http://sscce.org)" (check the link), and even if you weren't asking a question on this site, it is a good debugging tool that you'll want to have in your Java coding tool belt.

> If this were my problem and I were seeking help here, I'd take a little time to create and post a [minimal example program](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) or [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) since I'd know that this would be the best and quickest way to get folks to fully understand my problem and then help me.

> Without seeing pertinent code, it's anyone's guess what you might be doing wrong. Please consider taking a little time to create and post a [minimal example program](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) since this would be the best and quickest way to get folks to fully understand your problem and then help you.

> Probably the best way to get us to fully and quickly understand your problem would be if you were to to create and post a [minimal example program](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), a small but complete program that only has necessary code to demonstrate your problem, that we can copy, paste, compile and run without modification. This code would be small enough to post in its entirety completely within your question as code-formatted text.

> I don't think that your posted code and text is adequate to allow us to be able to understand your problem enough to answer it. If you don't get a decent answer soon, consider creating and posting a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example Program](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

> If you don't get help soon, consider creating and posting a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example Program](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) where you condense your code into the smallest bit that still compiles and runs, has no outside dependencies (such as need to link to a database or images), has no extra code that's not relevant to your problem, but still demonstrates your problem.

> ... but as in most things, the devil exists in the details. If you need more specific help, then you first, please tell us more of the details and show us your pertinent code, preferably as a [minimal example program or MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

> Please read the [mcve] link as it will tell you precisely what we need. This **will likely** require significant work on your part since we're not going to want to see the whole program if it is more than a page or two in length, which means that you'll likely have to create a new small demo program, but it is work well worth it as it will allow us to be able to compile, run, test and modify your code, giving us a much greater understanding of your problem.

---

One of my biggest complaints about the [mcve] link is that it doesn't directly mention not posting links to code repositories, and this I believe can lead posters to falsely believe that this might be OK. I also think that any comment requesting an MCVE is just that, a request, and not a requirement, since that's all that a comment can be, and the motivation part comes from, "if you don't get any decent answers soon...", The requirement part comes from a vote-to-close, of course, and this applied with discretion.

As for avoiding the [MCVE] link, I think that the best of both worlds is possible. Summarize the salient points in the comment, but also provide a link that gives the details. This provides a motivated poster more useful information that can be used to improve their question.

Comment: The point of my template (and no one should ever be typing that template for their comments; it's a copy&paste job or a custom shortcut job) is NOT to include any links but instead make them WANT to do what needs to be done and then immediately, right within the comment, give them **exact** step-by-step dummy-proof instructions. It doesn't tell them to "read" anything because that feels like a chore. No one wants to read a manual. But they do want to get sensible answers.

Comment: @WebDevBooster: I think that the best of both worlds is possible. Summarize the salient points in the comment, but also provide a link that gives the details. This provides a *motivated* poster more useful information that can be used to improve their question.

Comment: *"I think that the best of both worlds is possible."* -- Sure! I'd agree with that. A short reference link probably wouldn't hurt. I personally think it's more effective without a link but ultimately I have no data to back that theory up. So, anyone can use that template in any way they like.

Comment: The basic question regarding the MCVE link is: How many people are actually gonna click that AND read that entire page as opposed to just following the crystal clear step-by-step instructions outlined right there in the comment? I guess, there probably will be a small percentage who will read the MCVE page. So, a link wouldn't hurt.

Comment: These are very good, thanks Hovercraft. I use the boilerplate messages [from here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/SO-Close-Vote-Reviewers/auto-comments/master/sites/stackoverflow.com/questions.md).

Comment: @WebDevBooster "give them exact step-by-step dummy-proof instructions"...Doesn't that completely contradict the usage of a template? Each low-quality question lacks different information. One has too much/few _(ir-)relevant_ code, the other lacks context, and most of them lack explicit error messages/stack traces. Your template matches only so few of these cases, that it doesn't achieve what you want it to. If you want to leave comments that are well-received because OP sees someone _cared_ instead of posting canned mcve comments, then _do_ so instead of using templates.

Comment: @halfer: yes, I keep forgetting about those helpful links. Thanks for including them.

Comment: @RenéVogt I probably should have `highlighted` much better and **bolder** that this is NOT supposed to be a "be all, end all" template. It's a template to use exclusively for those case where it actually fits 100% and NOT to use in all other cases. I happen to have a few of those cases per day. Maybe 2 or 3 cases daily. For other cases, I use different templates i.e. those that fit 100% there.

Comment: @WebDevBooster if an asker of a low-quality question can't be arsed to read ~1.5 pages of loose text, what chances do they have on the site going forward? Of course if they had been capable of comprehensive reading they probably wouldn't have asked their question in the first place...but I tend to believe that spoon-feeding is never the answer.