# Collection of standardized comments

Tags: discussion, comments

It appears to me that it happens quite often that (new) users

- mistake meta-sites of the SE-network with the respective main site
- mistakenly post unrelated questions to one of the main sites (not on topic for the specific site)
- don't put enough effort in producing a good-quality question/answer
- mistake the SE-network for a place where their homework is done for them
- post link-only answers
- etc., etc.

In such cases we often leave generic comments to the OP such as:

- "Welcome to Meta-StackOverflow! This site is for discussions, bug reports, and feature requests regarding StackOverflow; unfortunately, we have to mark this question as "off-topic" for this site. Please post your question on the [correct site](https://stackexchange.com/sites), and check to make sure your question is on-topic and meets the criteria-standards for the site you've chosen."
- "Welcome to SO ;) Please read this article on [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) in case you haven't done it already. A good question would include a proper description of what you are trying to achieve, your code (or the relevant snippets) as well as your efforts showing what you have tried so far and possible error messages. It is also advisable to provide a full [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).."
- "Can you please add the relevant code"
- etc., etc.

and alike. On mathSE-Meta I've seen a [guide for commenting](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4925/228959) for above mentioned cases, 
in addition there's already the useful script to use [auto-review-comments](https://stackapps.com/q/2116/34061) and @HovercraftFullOfEels 
[alternatives to standard biolder-plate-comments](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/362925/useful-alternative-to-mcve-links-and-the-standard-boilerplate-comments/362926#362926)

Now to my question: Would it make sense to compile a standardized and agreed-on collection of meaningful and applicable comments 
(maybe as a community-wiki, in the help-center or elsewhere) to be used in these cases for the benefit of having a guideline for comments users can follow if they wish to?

As usual on meta, please (down/up)vote to indicate your (dis)agreement.

Comment: _"If this is a homework, please add a tag"_ I've never seen anyone on SO, leaving these type of comments

Comment: @window.document:  *I* have.  And they're unpleasant.

Comment: @Makoto really? I thought homework questions are toxic and irrelevant for SO unless they are on-topic

Comment: @window.document If they are of good-quality, show a certain research-effort and provide some useful content for the future I wouldn't consider them as _toxic_

Comment: @iLuvLogix no one would then, but I didn't understand _If this is a homework, please add a tag_ there's no tag for homework, so why would anyone say to add it in the question?

Comment: @window.document:  Some people just don't know better, or they assume that tags are how to categorize specific questions.

Comment: @window.document Have you read the [CW](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4925/list-of-comment-templates) on mathSE that I was referring to in my question?

Comment: @iLuvLogix that is mathSE and they have a seperate tag for [homework](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/homework) not on SO

Comment: @window.document That's why I said in the comments that I merely used it as an example -  but you are right that it's not applicable for SO ;)

Comment: Why use it for an example even? This is SO meta and here we talk about workings of **StackOverflow** not mathSE

Comment: @window.document I'm so sorry, please excuse my ignorance and lack of understanding ;)

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=idownvotedbecau.se is another set of discussions on somewhat similar idea. Summary: canned responses are less kind than no responses at all...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

***No***, it would not make sense.

While I have the unshakable suspicion that we've had this conversation before somewhere on Meta, these kinds of comments aren't really going to accomplish what you *think* they should.  100 times out of 100, anyone who commentates to the above effect gets the brunt of the attention from the OP who posted that question, to the tune of a debate or discussion about the merits of the question.

Stack Overflow gets [**on the order of 7,000 questions a day**](https://stackexchange.com/sites#questionsperday).  We do not have the people out there to dedicate to responding to all of the comments which would be left on those questions.  Since we don't have the resources to handle the wave of comments, it makes more sense to me to simply *not* comment and just

## vote to close the question

if it's worthy of any of those kinds of comments at all.

Also, in regards to this comment:

> "If this is a homework, please add a tag"

[We've already established this.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/308252/1079354)   There is no such thing as a homework tag and asking people to add one is ***incorrect***.

Comment: I get your point with the amount of moderation needed - btw I'm not suggesting to add that tag - I merely used it as an example ;)

Comment: [Exhibit A](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/382449/why-difficult-subjet-opening).  Askers will latch onto commentors in an attempt to gain more information.  The chances of them actually reading and understanding the comment is...less than good.

Comment: @fbueckert:  I think there may be a language barrier at play here *too*...

Comment: No argument there.  But it's still a good display of what happens when someone comments.

Comment: @fbueckert I get your point - so it would be rather counterproductive according to Makotos and your explanation..

Comment: @iLuvLogix Not to mention the inherent assumptions that go into canned comments; your second example is a good one to use for that.  Just by having that comment, it implies that we should have a homework tag, and that homework of any stripe is perfectly fine.  It *sounds* harmless, and can help posters, but thinking of the broader implications, it's really not.

Answer (score 2):

> Would it make sense to compile a standardized and agreed-on collection of meaningful and applicable comments

We already have that. When a post is closed ("put on hold"), the OP receives such a comment automatically depending on close reason. Complete with links to various help files.

There is not really a need for anyone to post the kind of comments you mention before closing has happened. Though if people want to do that still, there's no harm in it.

Comment: I disagree with the "no harm" piece; we now introduce an expectation upon the participants who decide to comment to that effect to engage with an OP.  There's no implied actual moderation happening (e.g. downvoting, vote to close), so this feels counterproductive given how much time it would take from someone trying to respond to these questions.

Comment: @Makoto Good point - do you want to add that to your answer?

Comment: @iLuvLogix:  I feel like I implicitly address this concern with the sheer volume of questions we get per day and the emphasis on voting to close the question...

Comment: @Makoto That's a good point, but most of the people leaving such comments seem to be veteran users who also cast close votes. As for "effort" I don't agree, most people doing this (I don't, personally) likely have prepared copy/paste. A whole lot less effort than to hunt down a duplicate for sure.