# Should edits to change versions on an answer be accepted?

Tags: discussion, review-queues

In this answer https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/30246598 I Reviewed to reject the edit, as it only changed `0.5+` to `0.50+`. The answer already had a score of 5 as at this post showing that the answer was actually a helpful answer even without the change,

> Ignore improvements that can be made outside the code block (spelling, grammar, etc.)

On a different review https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/30247519, I reviewed to accept the edit as it improved the readability of the code properties, Please assist me understand why this reviews were incorrect

Comment: the first review, was incorrect. While the edit is quite small, correcting the versioning is an important fix. In the second, making things that aren't code code formatted is incorrect.

Answer (score 7):

Kevin B already answered why [in the comments](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/412911/should-edits-to-change-versions-on-an-answer-be-accepted#comment878197_412911), but here's the longer version with sources.

[The editing guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/editing) include:

> - **To correct minor mistakes** or add updates as the post ages

In the case of the first review, you can tell it's a typo from the context. Read the original line carefully:

> FYI, the editor.focus() docs you're referencing are on Slate **0.47**, and **the API has changed significantly in 0.50+** (if you're using the Transforms.select or ReactEditor.focus API, you're on **0.5+**)

If you're in 0.5+, you can't be on 0.47 and not have the new APIs. Based on how the API changed in 0.50, you can more or less reason your way to 0.5+ being a typo of 0.50+. Useful answer or not, it's still a change that should be made. In either case, it most *definitely* doesn't match your edit rejection reason:

> This edit was **intended to address the author of the post** and **makes no sense** as an edit. **It should have been written as a comment or an answer.**

It wasn't meant to address the author, and it most definitely makes sense as an edit. It doesn't make sense as an answer, and the comment would at best be "Did you mean "you're on 0.50+"?" resulting in an edit from someone, possibly a different 2k user or editor, which is just editing the post with extra steps. Also shockingly redundant of the editor is relatively well-versed in React and can tell it's a typo not just based on context, but based on knowledge of the libraries/APIs in question.

---

Over to the second one, it more or less exclusively added useless backticks. As a reminder, [code is primarily meant for code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/254995/6296561), and none of the currently accepted excptions apply; i.e. not filetypes (JSON) or formats (GeoJSON) or the concept of rendering. The highlight of `map` is completely redundant, because the sentence refers to the concept of a map, and not something that might be justifiable to code highlight under the filename or micro-snippet exceptions (assuming you use a chat service that supports markdown, would you ever write "Sure, just need to check the `map` first"?). The last one left is `react-leaflet`, which is an edge-case. While it's [okay to use code formatting](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/369568/6296561) for package names, the current consensus is also:

> It **shouldn't** be compulsory, or something that bothers an editor so much that they **feel compelled to edit an answer only, or primarily, to add that formatting in,** when it's not appearing in the context of actual code

[The other answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/254994/6296561) on the meta canonical on non-code text illustrates what that type of edit edit does as well; it uses backticks as `redundant` emphasis, `resulting` in a post `with out-of-place` code highlights that serve no other purpose than to `emphasise` random words, based on what the editor feels is "relevant".