# How to format class names in plural form?

Tags: discussion, formatting

How should I format class names when I speak of objects in plural? See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11318942/1843468) excellent answer as an example. The relevant parts are sentences like these two:

> Just like `Activity`s, `Fragment`s may be destroyed by the system when memory resources are low. [...] all of the `Activity`s attached `Fragment`s will also be destroyed.

Apart from the missing apostrophe behind the second `Activity`, it looked confusing to my eye. I read "Just like `Activity s` ..." and wondered where in the code there would be an `Activity` named `s`.

Even moreso outside of the blockquote, since the `code` gray is much closer to the regular background white than the

> blockquote `code` gray is to the blockquote's background gray.

What do you think is the best way to format class names when they are required to be different from the actual classes' name?

1. *Exclude changes from the code tag, accepting the gap and improper spelling:*
   Android uses `Activity`s and `Fragment`s.
2. *Include the changes in the code tag:*
   Android uses `Activities` and `Fragments`.
3. *Paraphraze:*
   Android uses `Activity` and `Fragment` objects.
4. *Do away with the code tag if you cannot use the actual class name:*
   Android uses activities and fragments.

Comment: Worth noting, the blockquote background color on regular SO is yellow not grey.

Comment: @ryanyuyu Now that you said it... indeed it is. But that makes the difference even more obvious there.

Comment: "school of fish", "pride of lions", "murder of crows"... we urgently need a cool collective noun for instances.

Comment: @yivi I was about to add a flock of activities when a herd of fragments crossed my path.

Comment: @yivi A *heap of objects* or a *stack of instances*. Obviously.

Comment: I abide to @deceze ’s superior wisdom. There, problem solved.

Comment: [easy](http://mentalfloss.com/article/551081/collective-nouns-groups-animals): a descent of classes, a dangle of pointers, an overflow of stacks, a race of threads, a throw of exceptions, a scurry of lambdas, a walk of heaps, a mutation of constants, a run of tasks.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This may be a bad example, since it should probably be phrased as a pure English sentence without reference to any specific code. Here's maybe a better example, in which I'm trying to refer to specific classes in an explanatory sentence:

> Android has a notion of *activities* and *fragments*. Activities are implemented by the `Activity` class. You can create a list of such `Activity` objects*. Each `Activity`** will be processed in turn.

* The choice here is between *"such `Activity` objects"* and *"such `Activity`s"*. The latter one is rather awkward, so err on the side of saying "`Activity` objects".

** This is used as shorthand for *"`Activity` object"*. Since that phrasing was already used in the previous sentence, it's fine to shorten it here.

So, whenever you refer to a specific class, use code markup, and use the literal name of the class without grammatical alternations. *If possible*, for purely stylistic reasons, I'll go with a grammatical alteration *after* the code; for example when talking about `Task`s. It uses the literal class name, but also uses proper grammar within the sentence. If that is awkward, use phrasing like "`Xyz` object" instead. If you're not talking about a specific class, don't use code markup.

Comment: I like this answer even more than the answer given on the question mine has been made a duplicate of by now.

Answer (score 9):

They're talking about the **concepts** "activities" and "fragments". I wouldn't use code formatting for that.

The same goes for example for a "stream", which is a concept in many frameworks such as Java and .NET. You don't highlight each instance of the word `Stream` with inline code when explaining something about that topic.

Yes, these concepts have classes named after them, but not each time it occurs it is about the class name. So simply remove the code formatting when it's not about code.

And yes, I'm allergic to overuse of inline code.

See also: [When should code formatting be used for non-code text?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254990/when-should-code-formatting-be-used-for-non-code-text)

Comment: This answer doesn't address what to do if you *are* referring to actual class names.

Comment: My point is that you should write your post in such a way that you won't need inline code highlighting.

Comment: Personally, I like inline code for class names. It makes it easier for me to follow the posting, because the eye gets hooked on the class names and finds references to it in the text, like "Using a `PrinterWriter` makes using a `BufferedWriter` superfluous." But that's just my personal favor.

Comment: @LWChris I'm not entirely against using inline code highlighting, but it's easily overused.