# Am I the only one seeing the '90s retro theme, with the unicorns and sparkles?

Tags: support, april-fools, time-machine

I am seeing a distinctly *different* Stack Overflow:

[image]

The site now has a '90s "Geocities" feel, complete with unicorns, sparkle trails, gaudy backgrounds, and `<marquee>` tags.

This is happening to me on Google Chrome. I have never installed any plugins or user extensions. I believe this is coming from Stack Overflow.

Am I the only one seeing this? What is causing this to happen? Did the site get hacked or something?

Comment: Can someone kindly explain the reason of `down-votes` ?

Comment: I downvoted because you just posted a `comment` that used `code formatting` for something that `wasn't` code.

Comment: [Context](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/254995/6296561) for Cody's comment

Comment: @CodyGray I appreciate for your point, but what is the best title which should brief the question body? any advise please

Comment: How can we turn it back on after clicking the clock button ? :'(

Comment: @Pac0 Click the clock button again.

Comment: It's glorious !!! Nice april fool day prank

Comment: I love this.. let's keep it beyond April Fools please!

Comment: I mean, really, what are the odds you're the only one seeing it, or that it got hacked, considering the date?

Comment: Ahhhhch, me eyes!!! Hats off to SO for blinding a poor student. To the f̗u͇͔͖̟͙͈t̪̮͙u̟͉̙̪̻re͓͔͙̼̦!̭ Ṫ̥͐̓̒ͣͭ̽ȟ̲͐̑̉e̠̹̪͉ ̟͚̳̗̩̝͋f̱͆̔͛͋̅̈ṵ͕͎͉̺̻͊͛̆t͇̹͉͎̠̩̘̐̏̽̇̑̂̚ȕ͓̥̠̭͔r̰̹̰̣͍̜͎͂ͦ̒ͨ̒̉ḛ͓̜͇͒̓̏̂ͤ͂̚!̣̱̙̞̻̈͆ͬ͛ͭ̇̂ͅ

Comment: Thank God there's a way to turn this off. :)

Comment: @TrebledJ How did you do that?! XD

Comment: @Harsh [How does Zalgo text work?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6579844/1115360)

Comment: in fact I was thinking, wtf on this page! those sparkies are really annoying, then I see the unicorn and the stackoverflow panel jjj good prank..btw the wallpapers pfff..jj

Comment: Where can I download this Theme for my next admin panel? Or better, maybe it's a js plugin? Like `npm install self-loathing`.

Comment: Where did you see unicorns? I can't seem them

Comment: You're not the only one. It's like stack overflow got taken over by... nevermind.

Comment: @RooiWillie for some reasons, sometimes the clock button just disappear completely, I land (sometimes) on the original Stack Overflow page unchanged.

Comment: I hope it's permanent.

Comment: I actually would like this as a permanant feature of Stack Overflow.

Comment: @CodyGray  Well I am not sure this question should consider as duplicated, the referred question is posted `14 Hours ago` where this question has posted `20 Hours ago` so what is your comments about this? Any comment would be good

Comment: It was closed as a duplicate of the official announcement of the feature. I think that's reasonable. Jon should have posted that announcement earlier, but he slept through his alarm.

Comment: I seriously thought i was on some dodgy mirror site... had to use another computer because I thought I was infected.

Comment: On comment from TrebledJ 22, it contains a strange visual effect

Comment: @SebastianOscarLopez Yes I can see it. I don't know why it is happening.

Comment: This was cute once, and is now super annoying. The clock icon should disable it permanently.

Comment: It does, @Rob. The cookie is just different for each site in the network.

Comment: proof from html :
<img src="https://meta.stackoverflow.com/content/Img/april-fools-2019/headline.gif?v=f81430a4e488" alt="Welcome to Stack Overflow">

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/382111/announcing-the-stack-overflow-time-machine

Comment: I hate it.  Please never do it again.  It is funny but then it is annoying.

Comment: @FlorianF do you hate this feature? Some people got scared they thought that may be this is because of any virus and then tried another PC. Personally I liked it.

Comment: I hate it just as I hated this kind of page in the 90's.  It is not the internet of the 90's, it is the worst of the internet of the 90's.

Comment: It wouldn’t be any fun to satirize the *best* Internet of the 90s, @Florian.

Answer (score 93):

It's clearly an April Fools' Day prank, as is tradition on Stack Overflow.

The Stack Exchange network follows UTC time, and it is already April 1, 2019 in [some areas of the world](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC%2B14:00).

Comment: Ohh, but here is still 31 March, I mean here in Dubai

Comment: Stack Overflow goes by UTC time. Somewhere in the world, it is already April 1, 2019.

Comment: @AyazShah SE has a habit of starting early and ending late to cover all timezones. It's already april 1st in some parts of the world, and this will continue until the last timezones exit april 1st

Comment: What does Stack Exchange observing UTC have to do with it being April 1 in some parts of the world, beyond the absence of daylight saving offsets?

Comment: It is a poor way of conveying the point that Stack Exchange is designed for a *global* audience, and thus does not tie itself to a particular timezone.

Comment: Would have expected to see a nineties pair of glasses ...

Comment: They *are*, @rene. I haven't updated my style since then.

Comment: @CodyGray `and thus does not tie itself to a particular timezone.` UTC is a timezone and you say in your answer it follows UTC time. Maybe the *and* in your answer should be a *but*?

Comment: @Zoe a good april fools joke ends at noon though. - So it ought to be up for 36 hours.

Comment: @paul23 every hour it's noon somewhere (during some hours even in different timezones). ;)

Comment: How annoying. It is March 31 here .... can't they check my profile?! Bit pointless if you ask me!

Comment: I can't stop moving my mouse around and watching the confetti

Comment: Is this the gathering point for the thickest people on Stack Overflow? Come on folks, you can turn it off if you don't like it.

Comment: whew. Let me say again whew.

Answer (score 59):

I would like to congratulate Stack Overflow, they did a fantastic job of re-creating the '90s. I guess they may not have considered that many current SO users don't actually know what the internet looked like in the 90s? In any case, the marquee at the top, the Comic Sans text, the lime green borders, the tiled background, cursor trailers - marvelous stuff!!

I have to admit that you suckered me with the new theme for approximately 2.578 seconds - I had just visited a meta question of mine regarding a tag that had officially been burninated and I thought the theme was a celebration of that. Then I checked the time and realised it wasn't all about my question at all.

**Edit:** OMG there's even a guest book!! ROFLMAO!!

Comment: Proudly built in Notepad...

Comment: This answer best viewed with Netscape Navigator.

Comment: We're missing a music theme that starts to play upon opening the page.

Comment: Thank you for mentioning the guest book! I would have missed that completely! Evidently I need to scroll more!

Comment: First i thought i had a virus on my computer, then i thought SO got hacked, THEN i looked at the date and relized it was 5 to april fools :D
Love it!

Comment: @CodyGray and better viewed in 800x640.

Comment: I like the fires next to the HNQ

Comment: Ah, good old days when there was no build tools, no Javascript frameworks, and people gave values to developers / Programmers.

Answer (score 30):

Personally It bothering me, so to back to the original site just click to the button in top :

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, this seems to auto-disable itself for new tabs :/ This kinda reminds me [of last year](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/308570/332043)

Comment: Yes, april fools are supposed to be funny, why make it so painful? Even in the 90s not many sites were so bloated. Sigh. It's monday, you need a quick answer and... holy crap (ok, it's not yet monday here in France, but I know I will eventually need something on SO).

Comment: would be nice if it were a toggle (once you touch it I'm not able to turn it back on ; of course I want to annoy people behind me who are looking at my screen)

Comment: @Zoe huh? Not seeing this. Do you have a tm2019 and tm2019d cookies?

Comment: @Braiam [it was a bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/325996/332043). It has since been fixed. The forced per-site toggle still persists though

Comment: THANK YOU, I think I was legit on my way to a migraine, or seizure.

Comment: Pretty annoying, please just have a global toggle for all SE sites next year...  April Fools pranks are funny the first time, but not when repeated across all sites (and the toggle wasn't remembered even in one site initially)...  Also please use the user's local time, this started before noon on March 31st for me.

Answer (score 12):

For the sake of completeness, a screenshot of the guestbook and footer of the page:

[image]

Comment: unfortunately, the people are fake

Answer (score 8):

As the website indicates at the bottom right corner, it is "BEST VIEWED IN Netscape 3.0". Not sure why it is not showing the W3C compliant banners, but if you setup Netscape 3.0 it should fix it all.

[image]

If you cannot find Netscape 3.0 (a more recent version will not work), you can conveniently click the little clock at the top right corner in order to instantly setup Netscape 3.0.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Oh! That was supposed to be comic sans! I’m both sad and happy I don’t see it that way on my iPhone. Sad because I don’t get the full retro experience. Happy because now I know my phone is clever enough to replace comic sans with something not entirely as atrocious.

For the curious, this is what it looks like to me:

[image: iPhone screen shot of tags and comments under the question]

Comment: You cannot use your iPhone to view this site because iPhone didn't exist back in the 90s.

Answer (score 1):

No, you're not the only one seeing it. It seems to be an April fools joke...

...which unfortunately cannot be permanently disabled right now in Chrome as it seems.

**Edit:**
It seems this bug fortunately has been fixed: [Please don't show the licorne on each question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/382051/please-dont-show-the-licorne-on-each-question/382067#382067)

Comment: I see it today...

Comment: Why would you want to turn it off? This is FANTASTIC!!!!