# Please don't show the licorne on each question

Tags: bug, status-completed, april-fools, time-machine

I notice the <strike>strange</strike> nice design when navigating the site and that it can be deactivated by clicking on the "clock" icon:

> [image]

but when I navigate to another question it shows the same April Fools' design.

Can my choice to show the normal design be kept so I don't need to click it on every question I go to?

Comment: @CodyGray what is not clear on the question?

Comment: I don't really understand any of it. Are you complaining about the April Fools' Day prank? It's customary around here. It'll be gone in ~1 day.

Comment: @CodyGray the new design is showing each time I click on a question and each time I need to click the clock to remove it ... I guess it's good to remember my choice and not having to click each time to disable it

Comment: It seems to be persisted on a per-page basis! Disabling it for one question persists the setting just for that single question. The theme will reset once I open a question I have never opened before.

Comment: @MarkusUnterwaditzer yes and for me (having a poor inernet connection) it's very buggy :/

Comment: The same thing happened last year, it seems ([link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/308570/284827)).

Comment: @CodyGray Pranks are fine, and funny (and nostalgic in this case :) ... but being told the same prank for one day **is not**, so allow at least to disable it on a per user basis (or a 5 times count down or something). I personally will say bye for today because it became one too many.

Comment: I'm actually OK with the new design of SO (everything's better with unicorns). I'm actually more annoyed that I have to close this annoying "Back to the future" popup on every page. The site needs to remember my choice whatever it is.

Comment: @WaiHaLee nooo, really not the same. The duck was fun and not intrusive. This year it's all over the place and renders the page useless.

Comment: @ShadowWizard what I meant was that last year the April Fools' event also appeared to have a bug. As it happens I completely agree with you: this year's event is **far** more intrusive, and the garish colours and mouse trails gave me a headache when I tried to push through it. Having to disable on each page this year is not a tenable workaround.

Comment: [Same request on network meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/325996/how-to-disable-time-travel-entirely).

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Your preference should persist across questions on each site now. Enjoy :)

Comment: Oh, thank you very much! While you're at it, can you apply the same logic to this "Back to the future" popup? I still have to close it on every page.

Comment: @defaultlocale That should be fixed in the current build as well - we'll remember a dismiss on it only resetting that dismiss if you opt back in (and it'll immediately remember again), so users know how to get out at all times.

Comment: Thanks a lot for fixing this issue! =)

Answer (score 10):

You can disable it on a per-site basis setting a never-expiring cookie:

```
$.cookie("tm2019", "1", { expires: `Fri, 31 Dec 9999 23:59:59 GMT`, path: '/' });
```

Just paste this in your JS console (F12 should open the console in most browsers).

If you're like me and want to keep the design but remove the "Back to the future" popup, you should be able to hide it with AdBlock manually or with a rule like this:

```
meta.stackoverflow.com##DIV[class="js-toggle-popover s-popover ff-sans is-visible"]
```

Comment: It works thank you very much

Comment: Or you could just adapt the cookie path in web storage / cookies.

Comment: You can just set the expiry to the 3rd of april, since it'll be gone by then anyway

Comment: @ErikA Hope for the best, but prepare for the worst :)

Comment: Expecting you'll write next year's April Fools prank of SE. ;)

Answer (score -5):

It should **definitely** remember your choice and persist it for all pages.

Nice work Stack Overflow, it really made me smile, thank you.

For me, it doesn't bother having it for ~1 day, I can happily live with it. But I can really understand other users who are getting distracted or having page-loading issues because of this feature. So it would be really great to make this feature optional by allowing disabling it for good.

We appreciate your efforts.

[image]

Comment: This does not appear to be an answer.

Comment: Perhaps someone can devise a bypass solution by looking at the code just above the ascii image shown above.

Comment: @HenningMakholm That's because it's not an answer. I just wanted to support the feature-request and share my opinion.