# Comic Sans font is missing in Ubun... er... Unix

Tags: bug, april-fools, time-machine

<s>Ubuntu</s> Unix users are barred from experiencing the full glory of this year's April Fools prank, as it relies on Windows 98 supplying the Comic Sans MS font used in headlines and several other places.

[image: UNACCEPTABLE]

For comparison: on Windows 98:

[image: WANDOWS]

This oppressive discrimination will not stand!

[image: DOZENS]

Comment: This post needs a screenshot from a windows computer...

Comment: hahahahaahahahaah

Comment: @user000001 Feel free to provide one

Comment: @MadaraUchiha: I can't, I'm on linux too. That's why I was interested in seeing how windows folks see it.

Comment: @user000001 here it is https://imgur.com/9emo7dS

Comment: @MadaraUchiha feel free to use mine, and maybe reupload.

Comment: @bracco23 Added! The foundation appreciates your contribution to the war efforts.

Comment: As a sidenote, was paying attention to multiple platform a 90's thing? Like, I'm too young for these details but If i have to guess, I'd say no.

Comment: [Isn't macOS unix?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1489/is-mac-os-x-unix) Works fine in Mojave.

Comment: @ArunaHerath MacOS didn't exist in the 90s :)

Comment: @MadaraUchiha Mac OS certainly did exist in the 90s. I believe you're confusing it with "macOS" (the new name for OSX)

Comment: You do not have comic-sans on the idevices, and yet we do get a [very nice looking alternative](https://imgur.com/a/G8v4Pw5). And it's even responsive! RWD on the 90's! And it's not using tables for layout! This time machine is bugged out.

Comment: I just posted [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/382105/7328782) what the font looks like on an iPhone.

Comment: Wait, so the site still looks pretty much as designed on Windows 98 supporting browsers?

Answer (score 46):

I don't think you get it, but this is likely by design. In the 90s, Unix users we oppressed, not bowing down to Microsoft's glorious Embrace, Extend, Extinguish ideals.

I think it works *exactly* like it's meant to.

Don't forget, Microsoft is a firm believer in oppression in 1998!

Comment: Ah, yes, MS-bashing. So 90s.

Answer (score 18):

You forgot the $, as in Micro$oft

Answer (score 8):

Use [Comic Neue](http://comicneue.com/):

```
sudo apt install fonts-comic-neue
```

It works as a drop-in replacement if you don’t have Comic Sans installed.

(Fun fact: I first installed `ttf-mscorefonts-installer` (don’t!), which made a lot of websites look horrible. Then I uninstalled it. That made those websites’ firefox tabs crash )