# What is "Have you considered accepting an answer or starting a bounty for this question"?

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer, warning-message

In 'Questions' section of Stack Overflow,

[image]

my questions are listed showing below. However, for the 4th question, the message "***Have you considered accepting an answer or starting a bounty for this question?***" is shown.

[image]

What is the message for?

[image]

Comment: That's so poorly positioned/formatted... that I'd think it were a bug.

Comment: I bet the message appears for questions that are (1) old (couple days maybe?) (2) have at least one answer (3) no answers are upvoted or accepted. It is to prompt you to indicate to others that your problem is resolved (by accepting) or to get more attention to the question to *get* it resolved by placing a bounty. Why would the site prompt you for this? Because "answered" questions (with either accepted or upvoted answers) are more valuable to the site than unanswered questions.

Comment: 2 weeks ago, the message was displayed for the too simple 4th question as soon as I posted the question and the message is still there. And for the too simple 3rd question I posted 2 or 3 days ago, the message appeared too as soon as I posted but in half day, I added more explanation then the message disappeared quite soon.

Comment: Well, *have* you considered accepting an answer or starting a bounty for this question?

Comment: Come to think of it, have you considered asking actual questions for other people, not just ones to immediately answer yourself?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi [You are aware that self-answering is encouraged, right?](https://stackoverflow.blog/2012/05/22/encyclopedia-stack-exchange/)

Comment: @Anonymous I am aware that asking a proper question and giving a proper answer is perfectly fine, even if asker and answerer just happen to be the same person.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi You're criticizing them for that, even though that's encouraged.

Comment: @Anonymous I am making a suggestion for them to get more community feedback on their content.

Answer (score 8):

All of the following [criteria](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214877/when-is-the-message-have-you-considered-accepting-an-answer-or-starting-a-bount/348533#348533) have to be true for the message “Have you considered accepting an answer or starting a bounty for this question?” to be displayed, according to SE employee [animuson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/246246/animuson):

> - The indicator is enabled for the site (enabled on all sites minus
>   per-site metas, Meta Stack Exchange, and Stack Apps)
> - You are viewing your own questions
> - You have the privilege to vote down
> - You do not have the privilege to cast close votes
> - The question does not have an accepted answer
> - The question is at least three days old and not more than 60 days old
> - The question has at least one answer and is not closed
> - The question does not have a currently active bounty and has not
>   previously had a bounty

According to Jeff Atwood, it automatically goes away after [60 days](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57707/a-suggestion-of-yes-no-button-in-front-of-this-have-you-considered-accepting-a/57708#57708) (earlier he said it was [1 month](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14594/can-we-have-an-option-to-disable-the-dont-forget-to-accept-reminder/14599#14599)).

The purpose is to remind you to either accept one of the answers or, if none of them solved your problem to your satisfaction, to start a bounty to attract new answers.

Answer (score -16):

I think the message appears for the questions which are not explained well or alternatively, are too simple. I have asked 2 questions in a too simple way on Stack Overflow so far. Then, these 2 questions had the message. Then, I added more explanation to one of them. Then, the message disappeared from the question. However, I have left the other question too simple still and the message still appears for it.

This is the other question which is the 4th question mentioning in the question section above. The 4th question only contains one single sentence, which is too simple.

[image]

So I think the message appears for questions which are too simple. To remove the message, you should add more explanation. This is the question which I added more explanation to, then, the message disappeared (The 3rd question mentioning in the question section above).

[image: The question has 3 sentences and 2 screenshots.]

Comment: Please refrain from adding code formatting to words which are not themselves code (in the screenshot, "AWS", "key pair" and "file" are not code. Neither is ".pem" but that's less well defined. See [When should code formatting be used for non-code text?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254990/215552)

Comment: I think the message went away because you interacted with the question. Voting on an answer, editing the tags, even making the question shorter probably would have done the same thing.

Comment: Why does a bad question mean that you'd want to put a bounty on it or accept an answer?  That doesn't make sense...  As @BSMP said, it probably has to do with the interaction.