# Is it frowned upon to use backticks around a word or even part of it to refer to some function or keyword as part of a sentence?

Tags: discussion, code-formatting, editing-help

I'm talking about things like "you can do that by taking your `usersArray` and [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)ping it to each user's `name`", essentially incorporating part of the inline code into the natural flow of the sentence where it makes sense, in order to tell the reader right away while they are reading the sentence that there are corresponding keywords/methods/etc. that they can use to do these things.

I use that quite frequently as I believe it's concise, but easily readable, and still conveys a lot of meaning this way (as opposed to "you can do that by taking your `usersArray` array and using the [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method to map it to each user's `name` property").

To elaborate further: If I assume the reader knows that mapping can be done with the `map` method, I wouldn't code-format it anyway. The way I used it so far was to turn the attention towards the fact that there is actually a method called `map` that can be used to map stuff. Another example would be something like "You have to `await` your promise" as opposed to "You have to await your promise using the `await` keyword". In my eyes the latter is just... awkward, and I find the former much easier to read. Things like "`map`ping" where only part of the word is the actual code are just the logical extension of that.

Then, today I saw [an answer that got edited](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/20920653/revisions) as follows: It originally said "Make `identity_t::operator[]` `const`ant." and was changed to "Make `identity_t::operator[]` constant.". The answer referred to adding a `const` qualifier to the operator `identity_t::operator[]`.

I looked at the edit summary, but it said nothing ("deleted 2 characters in body"), so my initial reflex was to roll back the edit, as I felt that it is the *opposite* of an improvement, but then I hesitated since I thought that the editor must have had a strong enough reason. So I thought, maybe this way of inlining is considered bad style, but I couldn't find any source for or against it and in fact didn't even succeed in finding *any* information about it because I was unable to figure out how to even search for it correctly. (Does this style have a name?)

So, my questions are: **What is the general opinion about this style (positive, neutral or negative) and why, and was the edit warranted and/or would a rollback be warranted?**

---

<sub>**Clarification:** This is *not* a question about using backticks for emphasis or other things that aren't code, so in my opinion it isn't a duplicate of [When should code formatting be used for non-code text?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254990/when-should-code-formatting-be-used-for-non-code-text), since this *is* about "Micro-snippets of code" in a certain sense, which is listed as acceptable use there. But this *exact* usage is not described (neither positively nor negatively) in the other question and its answers.</sub>

<sub>I'm sorry for the awkward title. I'm not sure how to best describe this in a short way.</sub>

Comment: Breaking the word "*constant"* up doesn't make sense to me. The fact that it contains `const` doesn't seem relevant. The context is that it is being used as a complete  word

Comment: `const` is code. "constant" is a word. Writing "`const`ant" allows us to shorten "make it constant using `const`" to "make it `const`ant" while still making it obvious that we refer to using the `const` keyword to achieve making it constant.

Comment: This for example: *"you can do that by taking your `usersArray` and `map`ping it to each user's name"*. usersArray is iffy, as, Yes, that's a variable and technically code, it isn't necessary... but not wrong, but "`map`ing" is wrong, as mapping is an action, not code (and breaking a word in half that way is awful)

Comment: `map` is code though, and I even linked the method in question. it is just overlayed onto the the word "mapping".

Comment: Yes, however, your usage of it is not code, it's concept.

Comment: Similarly, "var" in variable isn't code formatted for javascript, neither is "const" when you say "constant". It's useless noise at that point.

Comment: Well by that logic, writing "using the `map` method" is also still a concept... I mean, clearly I can see your opinion is that it's bad style, and I accept that, that's why I asked this question, but I still don't quite agree with where the line seems to be drawn here.

Comment: I'd argue map in that scenario also doesn't need to be code formatted. (just as it doesn't in this comment, as i'm not discussing code)

Comment: Hm. I see what you mean, but if I assume the reader knows that mapping can be done with the `map` method, I wouldn't code-format it anyway. The way I used it so far was to turn the attention towards the fact that there is in fact a method called `map` that can be used to map stuff. Another example would be something like "You have to `await` your promise" as opposed to "You have to await your promise using the `await` keyword". In my eyes the latter is just... awkward and I would see _that_ as unnecessarily noisy. Things like "`map`ping" are just the logical extension of that.

Comment: it isn't necessary to distinguish between await and await in a sentence about await. code formatting is optional there in both cases. The entire point of formatting is readability. A paragraph with a dozen in-line code blocks is disruptive, even if the code formatting is used "appropriately"

Comment: `map`ping I would consider _acceptable_ because it is actually a function (although I'd prefer "using `map`"  or similar). I would consider `const`ant totally unacceptable.

Comment: @CherryDT I'd argue that your Q _is_ a duplicate of that Q, and the accepted A tells you that it is OK to sometimes use code highlighting as you are, and that you will get disagreement on where the grey fuzzy line is

Comment: Hm, the only reason I'm disputing this being a duplicate is because I feel that this way a proper gathering of opinions is hindered, and my whole point was to shed some light onto that grey fuzzy area as it _isn't_ answered in the other Q... I mean, there was no real answer to my question "was the edit warranted and/or would a rollback be warranted?" yet, so what I gather from what you said is essentially that the edit _wasn't_ warranted, but since it's such a grey area, a rollback wouldn't be warranted either...? But wouldn't that conclusion be a bit problematic in itself?

Comment: It's a perfect scenario to prove why we need edits/reviews handled by people: it needs an amount of opinion/subjectivity to work even if it could be automated.

Comment: It’s not a gray area. Parts of words that happen to match code identifiers are not code. Code formatting should be used for code, not to highlight parts of natural language words.

Comment: @yivi OK but now that's the point I don't understand. Is "using the `map` method" acceptable? If it is, why does it suddenly become not acceptable if - to turn this around - the method name happens to also be part of a word that makes grammatical sense? Perhaps the `await` thing is a stronger example of my point. The way I see it: If something is _both_ code _and_ language, the union of their (positive) properties should apply. I have a Q that actually asks about a combination of Java and JavaScript, the rule of thumb "JavaScript quesitons shouldn't be tagged [java]" also won't apply...

Comment: Because a word that h`app`ens to have the same `let`ters as code `arr`anged in the same `order` isn't code. *even in the case of await*

Comment: Your last example is nonsensical though. It's just random backticks with zero meaning. Mine isn't. `app` has nothing to do with "happens", neither does `let` have anything to do with letters or `arr` with arranging anything. Nobody reading that sentence would understand that you'd want them to use the `app` gizmo to have something happen or to refer to the individual letters in their string using the `let` wunderwuzzi etc....

Comment: And wrapping await in an inline codeblock does nothing to help readability, regardless of whether you're saying use await or simply using it as part of an explanation. The sentence itself makes it clear what meaning was meant.

Comment: Are you saying that it's a mistake to expect a reader to understand that the use of the backticks around "await" was supposed to tell them that the thing they need to use (keyword, function, whatever - some "code thing") is also called "await"? If that's the case then - yeah I guess it's only noise at that point, since it wouldn't contribute any extra information as I intended. But that's where I'm not sure - I thought it's a neat and obvious way to convey that meaning, but I'm not sure how to find out whether that's true - from more than a few people. _Does_ this have a name I can google..?

Comment: in-line code ticks should be used in places where it will aid readability. it *can also* be used generally for any bit of the sentence that is actually code, such as "you should use `await`". there's no, rule, that states you must always use it for code in sentences, nor one saying you shouldn't, or shouldn't use it more than n times, it's a case-by-case basis. Always approach it from the view of readability. codeblocks are presented in a different font meant to make code easier to read, but it doesn't make sentences easier to read.

Comment: IMO, your example would be far easier to read this way: "You're trying to call a non-const function `identity_t::operator[]` on a const parameter in const function `long hash_identity_t::operator( const identity_t& x )`.

Make `identity_t::operator[]` constant.". The code is code formatted, the explanation is not.

Comment: Thank you, I guess it comes down the individual perception of readability. It seems you perceive this very differently from how I do. Hence I do value all those inputs because if I learn today that with this for most people the intended message doesn't come across and instead it _worsens_ the readability for them, then that means I'm missing my goal by writing things this way and I should reconsider. - However, this makes me feel even stronger about reopening this, because obviously I am not the only one using this style (at least the linked A did too)... others would also benefit from answers

Comment: FWIW: While I probably wouldn't have used `const`ant, I've certainly done this before, and especially when the identifier doesn't fit grammatically within the sentence. E.g., "Use `DateTime`s in these instances" or maybe something like "You `Save()`d the value". It's certainly a stylistic preference, and it's not a hill I'd die on, but I don't see a problem with it, and sometimes it aids in readability without needing to add in filler words to maintain the conjugation of the code.

Comment: As others have said, there are readability issues, which are notably subjective. In the edited answer you linked in your question, the `const` keyword had already been explicitly mentioned with code formatting 3 times in the immediately preceding sentence. That, IMO, was *more* than enough to communicate that the `const` keyword needed to be used. Putting "`const`ant" in partial code formatting was unnecessary in order to communicate that `const` should be used and makes the code formatting feel even more overused, although the OP there may have been trying for minor humor.

Comment: OTOH, IMO, your short sentence examples using "mapping" have "`map`ping" as the only place the `.map()` method name is shown, so code format is not just reasonable, but desirable, particularly in combination with linking it to documentation, in order to be clear that you're talking about the actual `.map()` method, rather than some possible other metaphorical way of mapping. For these, I'd probably prefer "[`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)ing" to be extra explicit, given the single use of `map`.

Comment: Generally positive to it if the meaning is "unambiguous"... But concerning the "`map`ping" Example, with no Context of any ProgLang in this Meta Qt, I first read and understood it as "... and (you can) ping it to each [whatever] using some `map` Object/Method/Command..." - I only realized/understood from the Comments that it meant "... and mapping it to each [whatever] using some `map` O/M/C..." (But I possibly/probably would have understood it correctly "directly" in the Context of the SO Qt...)

Comment: Another thing that is minor, but IMO still worth considering. If you are trying to view a stack overflow page from Google translate, content in `backticks` is not translated. I try and put everything related to the code (variable names, keywords, etc.) in backticks as a courtesy to people who might be trying to use Google Translate to translate from English to their native language.

Comment: Just say "a `const`" instead of "`const`ant". The latter is awkward and confusing to parse while reading.

Comment: `map`ping is harder to read than mapping or `map`. If the user does not know how to map something in their language than you will need to clarify with a code example anyways. If they do know how to, then you can just say "use a mapping" and be done with it.

Answer (score 59):

Code blocks mark a language boundary; only use them when your formatting helps to distinguish prose meanings from code meanings.

Partial-word code blocks can be particularly distracting or can impair readability; only use them with well-understood prefixes and suffixes.

---

The goal here should be to make it *clear* which words and marks you should read as their English (or other prose language) meaning and which words you should read as their code meaning. In a question about Android Java, this can mark the difference between:

1. finish your activity
2. `finish` your activity
3. `finish` your Activity
4. `finish` your `Activity`

And as in [Jeanne Dark's linked](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/413480/is-it-frowned-upon-to-use-backticks-around-a-word-or-even-part-of-it-to-refer-to#comment882524_413480) question *[When should code formatting be used for non-code text?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254990/when-should-code-formatting-be-used-for-non-code-text)*, we all benefit by sticking to that rule, as opposed to misusing code blocks for emphasis of English words.

As you mention in your question, this can lead to a gray area where the English word and keyword are perfectly identical in spelling and part of speech, like `finish` (above) or `await` in JavaScript. Furthermore, many words may be readable as code simply by capitalizing them, which for example makes the difference between Activity and `Activity` less valuable. This is a matter of readability, and readability is somewhat personal: I'll tend to use capitalized Identifiers and [UpperCamelCase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camel_case) in prose, but as soon as I need `punctuation()`, spaced phrases like `do while`, or [`lowerCamelCase`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camel_case) I'll use backticks.

Regarding mid-word changes, one nifty thing about English in particular is its flexibility. As an English language user we can use language rules for pluralizing words and "verbing our nouns", or apply English spelling rules to words from other languages. "Futon" is a Japanese borrowing, so it has no natural plural; we pluralize it in English as "futons". "Xerox" and "Kleenex" are brand names, but if you say "Xeroxed" or "Kleenexes", the meaning is clear.

In this sense, borrowing [Jeremy Caney's examples](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/413480/is-it-frowned-upon-to-use-backticks-around-a-word-or-even-part-of-it-to-refer-to#comment882561_413480):

- ✔️ `DateTime`s: You're pluralizing the code noun `DateTime`, so this makes sense.
- ✔️ `Save()`d: You're adjusting the code verb `Save` to past tense, so this makes sense.
- ✔️ `fastRender`ing: You're adjusting the code verb `fastRender` to the present progressive, so this makes sense.
- ✔️ `then`able: You're describing an object you can call `then` on. This neologism [defined in the Promises/A+ specification](https://promisesaplus.com/#point-7) has become popular enough that it often does not need formatting at all, but I mention it because it follows the same rules and might have warranted this formatting earlier in the days of the Promise specification.
- ❓ `map`ping: I would use `map`ping to distinguish from `flatMap`ping, but "mapping" makes enough sense without the formatting that I'd probably skip backticks in most cases. The necessary doubling of "p" makes this especially awkward.
- ❓ `await`ing: Same here. In many cases it might not provide value, though  a novice would be less likely to ask "how do I await it?" if you say "`await` the value" instead of "await the value".
- ❌ `const`ant: The "-ant" cannot be understood as a suffix here. (You wouldn't put `var`ant or `Int`ant, would you?) Though you're hoping for the simultaneous reading of "constant" and `const`, the formatting and dual readings make this harder to treat as a single word than with the prefixes and suffixes used above.
- ❌ `var`iable, `app`lication, `man`ual, `dict`ionary, etc.

Note here that a ✔️ is meant to indicate which cases follow the described rule, not that those cases are *always* helpful or appropriate. Readers might find mid-word formatting to be distracting: unless you have character constraints (as in comments) you might favor one of the alternatives in [kaya3's answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/413490/1426891).

Comment: Thank you for the extensive answer. Could you just clarify what you mean by `const`ant being demonstrably wrong by comparing it with `Int`ant? I mean, "constant" is a word (the word `const` originates from) and "Intant" isn't. Do you mean the issue is that `const` alone wouldn't be a real English word and that's why it's a problem, so "it should be an `async`hronous" function would be bad too? (I do agree that the latter looks awkward because of the "ch" being broken up though.) Or, to use `Int`, something like "You need an `Int`eger for that".

Comment: @CherryDT "constant" is a word but in order to form it, you have to add "-ant" at the end of "const". This isn't a regular suffix in English. Compare with the examples above: "-s", "-d" (which can also be "-ed" in other situations), "-ing" (well "-<repeat consonant)ing" in this case due to spelling rules). These are regular suffixes that you can add to almost any word to turn it into a related word. By comparison "-ant" is not. Nor is "-iable", "-lication", "-ual", "-ionary".

Comment: Another very common example from the Android world is *["Intent"](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/android-intent/info)* (or is it *"intent"*?). Even [an official page](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent) spell it in two different ways (I am not sure if the context is different or not): *"An* ***intent*** *is an abstract description..."* and *"An* ***Intent*** *provides a facility..."* (my emphasis).

Comment: @CherryDT VLAZ has it right; it comes down to standard prefixes and suffixes, which I probably should have mentioned explicitly in the body. I consider these formatting conventions as some of English's fun undocumented rules, like those regarding [expletive infixation](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expletive_infixation) or [adjective order](https://www.bbc.com/culture/article/20160908-the-language-rules-we-know-but-dont-know-we-know). FWIW, I mean to describe what I believe are the rules here, not to declare them myself or empower grammar police (or `const`ables).

Comment: I'm not a fan of `map`ping... the small space reads as "map ping" to me.

Comment: "*you wouldn't put `var`ant or `Int`ant, would you?*" Well, no, but that's not how `const`ant is being used. Equivalents would be `var`iant and `int`eger (but the practice is still wrong overall).

Comment: @VLAZ Your comment seems like it is introducing a little bit of confusion. "Const" *isn't* a word in English... so it's not really correct to say "you add 'ant' to the end of 'const' to form constant"... you don't do that, you just... write the whole word, which is 'constant'.

Comment: @Tyler: Right, I am here *establishing* the rule that we should honor modification but not coincidence nor expansion of abbreviations. The dismissal of `var`ant is meant to demonstrate the inapplicability of -ant as a suffix, not to suggest that the OP would have used that in earnest.

Comment: @JeffBowman I don't think anyone was under the impression OP was using "ant" as a fixed suffix for data type keywords. It seems pretty obvious `const` is followed by "ant" because the word *in English* is "constant". In other words, OP is just... finishing the word.

Comment: @Tyler I believe that *despite* the author's intention, it reads initially as though they were using "-ant" as a suffix: their intended *word expansion of `const`* doesn't land because of the language change implied by the formatting, which would lead the reader to understand this as a morphological boundary instead. Based on your other comments, I think we largely agree here: I'm using the phrasing to demonstrate the applicability of my rule, not to misinterpret theirs.

Answer (score 53):

I think occasionally it is OK, but most of the time a different phrasing only costs one extra word, and adds enough extra clarity and readability that the trade-off is worth it:

- "Use `DateTime`s in these instances" → "Use `DateTime` objects in these cases", unless "instances" is used in its technical meaning
- "You `Save()`d the value" → "You called `Save()` on the value"
- "`fastRender`ing" → "calling `fastRender`"

The term "thenable" has become accepted now, so you can just write "thenable" without any code formatting; but hypothetically if this term were not widely understood then I would favour writing "[thenable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/resolve)" without code formatting but a link to a relevant explainer. Or if hypothetically the term were so non-standard that there was no good explainer to link to, then perhaps it would not be best to coin the term yourself:

- "The object is `then`able" → "The object supports `then`"
- "It accepts a `then`able" → "It accepts an object supporting `then`"

So let's talk about "make it a `const`ant":

- If the reader knows what the `const` keyword means and what it does, then "make it a `const`" gets the point across perfectly well.
- So the extra "-ant" suffix is surely aimed at readers who don't already know enough about `const`. I argue that "make it a `const`ant" is not sufficient to explain to those readers, but just with a few extra words, "make it a constant using the `const` keyword" explains what `const` means and how to use it.
- Or, write "make it a [`const`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/const-cpp)" with a link to a relevant explainer.

The same applies for "`async`hronous", "`int`eger", "`dict`ionary" and so on: if you think the keyword or type name isn't enough, then either write a proper explanation or link to one.

This particularly matters when inline code is formatted with padding. On Stack Overflow, that padding is about as wide as a space character in regular text, so "`const`ant" takes an extra moment to read because you have to notice that the "space" between the 't' and the 'a' is not meant to separate two words. Compare the screenshots below: on the right, I manually edited the style to remove the horizontal padding.

[image]

All of that said, I don't "frown upon" this practice; I prefer to avoid it myself and I encourage others to avoid it (for the reasons outlined above), but I would never judge somebody negatively for doing it, especially in comments as opposed to answers.

Comment: I would rather describe this as "like Jeff's, but better/more accurate", rather than "different"; you both largely agree on the main points.

Comment: Indeed. We're not writing for fourth-graders here, IMO Stack Overflow content should be written like you would write a paper. The constant highlighting is nothing more than hindering the reader with constant brain-hiccups, highlighting words within words is doubling down on the hindering, what are you trying to achieve by doing that I wonder... I think people take programming optimisation and start to apply it to text.

Comment: You can even keep it more concise than the original, saying "make it `const`" instead of your suggestion of "make it *a* `const`".  That sounds grammatical to me, because `const` is something variables or methods can be.  (IMO, the edits CherryDT described were highly sub-optimal choices for fixing the readability problem, though, as they removed mention of the appropriate keyword or function names.)

Comment: I'm not sure our opinions actually differ here. I say "here are the undocumented observed rules about where you can break a word boundary" and yours seems to be "here are concise alternatives so you don't have to break a word boundary". They seem complementary to me, your text just weighs the readability cost a little heavier than mine does.

Comment: @JeffBowman That's fair. I said that my opinion is different mainly because your use of green checkmarks makes it look like you're endorsing some things which I am advising against. If you just meant to describe what seems to be accepted by the community then perhaps I misunderstood.

Comment: @kaya3 See my edits just now, including to the above-the-line summary: My checkmarks are more about demonstrating the rule than fully endorsing the behavior. I've likewise linked to your answer for alternatives.

Answer (score 12):

**Yes, when it impairs readability.**

"`const`ant" and similar constructs impair readability because they force your brain to make multiple passes over the word to figure out its meaning. Your brain first reads and parses the "const" part, then has to context switch to read and parse the differently-formatted "ant" part. Then it has to build a decision tree with the various possibilities it's determined, and traverse that tree using the context information present to weight the leaves and ultimately decide on an interpretation. Because "const" and "ant" are in two different contexts, the tree is deeper and wider than if it were simply reading a single word in a single context - in particular, there are far more potential paths for mistakes (e.g. is this intended to be "const" + [omitted space] + "ant"?) In short, your brain has to do a lot of work to get from "`const`ant" to "constant", even if you don't realise it.

When you write something, it is for others to consume, and you should focus on making it *easy* for them to consume. Arbitrarily syntax-highlighting words in paragraphs makes consumption unnecessarily difficult; arbitrarily syntax-highlighting parts of words is honestly just obnoxious. It doesn't have any positive effects, only negative ones, so in general... just don't do this.

But what if you really have a valid scenario to use this? Thankfully, English already has a way to explicitly represent a context switch: punctuation. I prefer to use the humble hyphen, so would write "`const`-ant", which tells your brain that the -ant is *intentional*, not a mistake. This means that while the decision tree has the same number of branches and leaves as with "`const`ant", far less weight is placed on the "possible mistake" routes, which means your brain is able to arrive at the correct answer of "constant" more quickly.

Be kind to your brain.

Answer (score 0):

This is obviously a question of style, and like all style questions, it is largely a matter of opinion, and thus endlessly debatable.

There's at least one additional factor which plays pretty heavily into this particular style question, though, and that is that *computer geeks purely love font changes*.  (I say this with no animosity towards computer geeks: I myself am a reasonably hardcore computer geek, and I purely love font changes, too.)

More normal people, on the other hand, tend to view excessive font changes as distracting.  There's no hard-and-fast rule about what percentage of font change is acceptable versus distracting, but we can certainly say that the number of changes which a computer geek thinks is perfectly dandy is likely to be well into the territory that a more normal reader finds distracting.

So the reasonably obvious conclusion is: don't overuse your ability to render keywords and other computer geeky identifiers in monospace/typewriter/`<pre>` font.  Make sure it's really necessary in order to eliminate ambiguity or aid comprehension; make sure you're not just showing off how much fun it is to use markdown syntax as you're texting.

---

[almost a separate answer]

There's also a linguistic component to this.  Most human languages have various kinds of markers for various parts of speech, although it's a defining characteristic of a language whether it does this a lot or a little.  For example, in German, all nouns are capitalized, while in English, only proper nouns are capitalized.

There's also a typographical convention, at least in English but I presume in other languages, of rendering foreign words in italics.  So people will write things like "I presume you're *au courant* on these stylistic issues?".

I believe that the impetus for rendering computer keywords and other identifiers in monospace font stems from an analogous urge.  An identifier in a computer language is significantly distinct from an ordinary noun, so it seems like maybe it ought to be distinguished in some special way.  Also, whatever computer language we're taking about is not English, so it might be useful to distinguish its syntax specially.  So, logically, the proclivity to render every single keyword and identifier in a sentence as monocase is, I believe, defensible — but still, it can be distracting when overdone.

And `const`ant, I'd say, is right out.

Comment: Aren't developers by definition computer geeks?

Comment: @CherryDT Certainly not. There's a huge range.  Some computer geeks are geeky even by computer geek standards.  And computer protramming (and related fields like web development) are now mainstream, so there are plenty of people — including I suspect a large fraction of the people asking questions on Stack Overflow — who are not (and would rather not be called) computer geeks at all.

Comment: I guess what I'm trying to say is that the definition of "computer geek" has become very ambiguous by now, I feel like people in the more technical spectrum have a different definition (that often doesn't include themselves) than people from different fields - which is why I think many non-developers would call developers computer geeks, while - as you just proved - many developers would not.

Comment: @CherryDT *people in the more technical spectrum* Now that is a lovely, lovely coinage. :-)  My point was just that if you're writing a Stack Overflow answer, you probably shouldn't assume that the OP is as much of a computer geek (however you define the term) as you are.

Comment: I am not convinced that the use of inline monospace is purely stylistic. The use of punctuation is also different from English prose, such that even ignoring indentation concerns [a.b(), c[d]] and _[a.b(), c[d]]_ are less readable than `[a.b(), c[d]]`. The utility of monospace extends for consistency to English-like words (`for`, `await`) for which italics would be similarly useful.