# How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?

Tags: discussion, faq, asking-questions, question-quality

I'm well aware that some research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users before they post any new questions, but I'm not sure just how much research effort is considered adequate.

I asked a question because I had found no search engine results that offered a clear answer, even after searching for almost an hour. Nonetheless, one Stack Overflow user was apparently dissatisfied with the amount of effort that I had put into this question, and they replied to my question with a critical comment. Should I take their advice and  refrain from asking for help even when I am not able to answer my own question with a reasonable amount of effort?

---

[Return to FAQ index](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251225/faq-index-for-stack-overflow)

Comment: This misunderstanding seems common enough. Even if I actually researched for days I could imagine someone may come and mistook my question as an opportunity to accuse *"you didn't do your homework"*. The research time also seems topic-dependent. That's why `Tell us what you found and why it didn’t meet your needs.` seems a good idea to me. Aaron Kurtzhal [emphasized](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261596/611007) it from the faq. Let the community decide whether your amount of research in the particular topic was sweet, and give you helpful, constructive feedback if it needs improvement.

Comment: Related: 1) [*Introducing Top Question Writers*](https://blog.quora.com/Introducing-Top-Question-Writers) 2) [quora.com/..../](https://www.quora.com/How-does-it-feel-to-be-a-Top-Question-Writer-of-2016/answer/Sergey-Yegorov). In case folks are curious about  how fellow Q&A sites at the [other side](https://xkcd.com/802/)  of the internet is doing it.

Comment: One thing that I discovered when asking questions here, half the time the process of making my question the best question I can ask leads me to answering my own question. The kind of putting things in order that is required in a good question makes the answer obvious.

Comment: Canonical link: `[How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/3257622)`

Answer (score 940, accepted):

A lot. Asking a question on Stack Overflow should be the *last* step in your process for finding an answer—if the information that you need already exists, then you should be able to find it before asking.

You want to

- Search. Like mad.
- Read documentation.
- Test your code.
- Troubleshoot.
- Read blogs.
- Find books.
- Follow tutorials.

After you have reached the end of your rope with the pain of not having the answer, that's when you can go ahead and ask. Because at that point, you will have done whatever research necessary to make it a good question worth asking. You'll have notes you can share to help inform the folks answering as to what you need. You'll have the **necessary background information to *understand* those answers when they arrive**. You won't have to contend with a poorly-written duplicate of a better answer that already exists somewhere else on the site. And you won't get frustrated by having your question closed, and the folks reading it won't get frustrated by having to close it.

It is important to emphasize that we want to help you, but you also need to help yourself. **The more effort you put into your question, the more benefit that you and future readers will get out of the answer(s)**. Understand that our time is not free, although we do not charge for it. Answering low quality, poorly researched, and/or duplicated questions becomes tiresome and does not contribute meaningfully to our goal of building a knowledge base, so please do your part to avoid this.

*With that said*, if the critical comment you're receiving is indeed rude—you should flag it. But you should also assume good faith, try to understand the frustration that motivated it, and strive to do better in the future.

Searching and researching is a skill, and mastery is achieved only through practice. The abilities you gain on the road to asking questions here will serve you well long into the future.

Answer (score 353):

In my opinion, there are five steps that one must take before asking a question on Stack Overflow:

**Step 1**: If applicable, research any core documentation + tutorials associated with your problem.

**Step 2**: Research your question on Stack Overflow (questions, answers, and comments if you can).

**Step 3**: If no results return from step 2, do enough extra research to formulate a *specific, well-written, on-topic, and objective question*.

**Step 4**: Ask.

**Step 5**: If step 3 provided the answer in enough detail from another site then   .... Answer your own question. So now the next person can searching will find the question and answer on SO.

Stack Overflow's mission is to be an objective Q&A site "*for professional and enthusiast programmers*". Period. It was not created to be a crutch for the lazy, *nor* was it created to be a "playground" for the experts. Stack Overflow has evolved to become, not just a programming Q&A site; but *THE* programming Q&A site.

It shouldn't matter if every other site on the Internet has the answer you're looking for; **if there exists a *specific, well-written, on-topic, and objective question* that has *not* been asked & answered on Stack Overflow, it should be**. Do not be intimidated into withholding questions simply because you don't hold a computer science degree in the subject, or are concerned about the precious minutes it would take away from someone else's busy schedule.

Yes, it is important for askers not to waste the time of those who volunteer to help them; but the whole reason the site was created was so that askers can save theirs.

Comment: You should add a step 5: If step 3 provided the answer in enough detail. Answer your own question. So now the next person can searching will find the question and answer on SO.

Comment: *"...simply because you don't hold a computer science degree in the subject..."* That's not the expectation. The expectation is that they not use StackOverflow as a *substitute* for the most basic research efforts. The OP claims to have spent an hour researching. Do you really believe that? The OP's question would be quickly answered at your step 1.

Comment: "It shouldn't matter if every other site on the Internet has the answer you're looking for..." Yes, it should. Because any author could self answer the question if so if they've done their research. That necessarily means that asking the question here would be using SO as "a crutch for the lazy," which you say is inappropriate. That's a contradiction.

Comment: there is always a gap between what is meant to be, and what it really is.

Comment: "The OP claims to have spent an hour researching. Do you really believe that? The OP's question would be quickly answered at your step 1." 

Of course it's true. Carrying out step 1 in sufficient detail to answer this question would take a full workday minimum, probably a full work week. That is a completely unfair amount of work to demand of a querent before they are permitted to ask the question.

Comment: "It shouldn't matter if every other site on the Internet has the answer you're looking for;" I would say that it should, for the simple reason that *if that's the case*, there's no reason that even preliminary research efforts would come up empty-handed.

Comment: Short, sweet questions add a lot of value to stack overflow.  Users should be encouraged to ask them -- after ensuring they aren't duplicates, of course.

"Reading the documentation" should *not* be construed to mean *mastering* every nook and cranny of the documentation.  There is a lot of documentation out there that is well written but fails to answer the most basic questions. Stack overflow has successfully filled that gap for many years.

Comment: Being able to compose a "short, sweet question" while also demonstrating that you've put the requisite effort into finding the answer on your own is a skill that, in and of itself, is difficult to master.  Those who *do* master it, though, need to remember it *is* hard to become proficient, and remain tolerant of less polished questions.  This does not, however, imply anyone needs to tolerate any form of "can you do my homework for me?" Such atrocities must be shut down immediately with a big slap of a ruler across the knuckles.

Answer (score 198):

The problem with this is that some people are better at searching the internet than others.  For some questions, a very slight change in the approach to the search engine can make a very large difference in the quality of the results. So we do get situations where someone has, in fact, made a nontrivial effort, and still ends up asking a question to which an expert can find the answer within three clicks.

On the other hand, there are some warning signs that should indicate to you that you're missing something simple, and you need to rethink how you are searching. Here we have a non-esoteric programming language. Here we have, indeed, what looks like a very simple question about this programming language. It should really bother you that you can't find an answer to your question.

If you can't think of anything else to search for in a case like this, searching for a tutorial can't hurt. And in this case, searching includes visiting the best web site(s) on the topic.

However, if you've tried A, and you've tried B, and you've looked for a tutorial, and you've taken a walk around the block, and you *still* have come up empty-handed, *then* ask a question here. You might get the occasional snide comment, which you should flag, but you will be justified in posting your question.

But if this keeps happening to you over and over, you really need to rethink how much effort you are actually putting into trying to find the answer on your own.

Comment: I think some people don't realize that Googling well is a real skill, one that not everybody has.

Comment: @MarkRansom That doesn't mean that people who can Google should be doing the work for those who can't, any more than we should be writing code for people who can't. If you don't have the skill, learn.

Comment: @IanKemp some skills aren't easy to learn, either you have it or you don't.  Good Googling requires knowing which search terms are going to be most relevant, how to properly combine them, and how to exclude results that don't relate.  If for example you don't realize that "golang" is often used as a synonym for the "go" language you're going to be pretty stuck.

Comment: "That doesn't mean that people who can Google should be doing the work for those who can't" No, that's exactly what it means.

Comment: The issue is that people with expertise are often not aware of how much their expertise helps them search for the right resource. If you don't know or can't guess what something is called, searching by descriptive phrases can work but often does not.
I think SO should have a section devoted specifically to requesting resources or terms, it would really help avoid polluting the programing forum with jargon questions.

Comment: This is why I have developed the policy, when telling people that their question is easy to answer by searching, of showing them the exact query I used and providing a link to the results, as well as the solution page.

Comment: If someone asks for help and you are able but unwilling to do so, it might be better to keep scrolling than to downvote and/or post a snarky comment. Everyone here is supposed to be a volunteer.

Comment: @MarkRansom If you can't learn to google, you likely won't be able to learn to program.

Comment: @JuanMendes maybe there's a correlation, but I wouldn't automatically jump to that conclusion.  And learning is a process, just because you haven't mastered something *yet* doesn't mean you never will.

Comment: +1. I find myself finding things some other people seem unable to. And I'm sure there are better people at that than me. This is always overlooked. It is a skill by itself. @JuanMendes afaik, programming is older than the internet.

Comment: I am sure we all have been in situations when we get such a mental block that you cannot distinguish the tree from the forest. Assuming simply that "_some people are better at searching the internet than others_" only covers part of the problem, and the degree to which it covers it is very hard to measure. Sometimes the mental block is so severe that you don't even know where to start.

Answer (score 174):

As moderators, we typically try not to make controversial statements; if something is accepted by the community, then we go with it; but this question is a shining example of where conventional wisdom is toxic to a sustainable community.

Don't misunderstand me; [I believe some respect of others is required to ask a good question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/210959/16587); but I don't think it's appropriate to go as far as the [top rated answer suggests](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/16587).

Effort is misused as a word; so much so that we should probably banish it from our vocabulary.

Stack Overflow was created as a repository of useful programming information; that means that if it's of use to others, it should be here, regardless of how many times the OP commits self-flagellation.

It's not about how much effort you put it; it's about how much you *respect* other people's time.  A common characteristic of bad questions is that they don't respect other people's time, because they:

- Have little to no punctuation
- terrible spelling
- don't provide the essential information we need to solve the problem
- don't tell us what the problem is
- expect us to write their program for them

If that's how your question looks, don't be surprised if it's closed.

If someone is knowledgeable about your programming language was able to find the answer rather quickly, but you weren't, *that's ok*.  That means the problem isn't you; the problem is the answer isn't easily discernible as such.  And now you've contributed to the community by making it easier for someone else to find the answer.

Comment: I would say the answer to the conflict of "easy to answer" and "need to do research" is that simple questions should usually be self answered. In other words, if they're not already on the site and someone wants to contribute, they should find the answer themselves and then post it along with the question.

Comment: I agree with @jpmc26 about self-answers. I often ask questions that I later discover were foolish, but they did not seem foolish after many hours of banging my head against the wall. If I find the answer, the least I can do is put it there in case someone else goes through the same though process that I did.

Comment: I do like this answer. I feel like users are sometimes criticized for not doing enough research work to be able to answer their own question. And there's always the possibility that an expert can simply make a connection that a non-expert cannot.

Comment: This answer embodies how I want SO to be as both a resource and a community. I can only hope we get more open-minded individuals like you to respond to questions. I feel like over the years I've dealt with a lot more snobby folks on here; it has left a bad stain on the site's reputation, IMHO.

Comment: This. It's so easy to spend hours and days researching ineffectively without really being aware of it, especially as a beginner (but still so as a pro; the field is too young). To then get treated like not having tried hard enough is just destructive.

Comment: I agree with this 100%. EVERYTHING in the top-rated (selected) answer is extremely subjective. Just because something comes easy to some it doesn't mean the other person hasn't researched sufficiently. Sometimes, mental blocks prevent you to research efficiently. Sometimes you spend time researching the wrong thing because you misunderstand the problem. It has happened to me many times, and I am sure it has happened to all of us. The assumption that low-quality questions are the result of laziness is simply not true in a lot of cases.

Comment: This is the best answer by far. When I'm searching for a problem, even a seemingly elementary one, SO links are very often my first port of call. This is because questions are often very closely related to a problem I have, and if there's an accepted answer then it's almost certainly going to fix my problem too. Having a large repository of quick answers to simple problems saves everyone time, and is one of the *best* things about SO.

Answer (score 129):

From the Help Center article [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), emphasis mine:

> Sharing your research helps everyone. **Tell us what you found and why
>   it didn’t meet your needs.** This demonstrates that you’ve taken the
>   time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious
>   answers, and above all, it helps you get a more specific and relevant
>   answer!

Doing research is only half of what you need. Your question did not explain what you found and why that wasn't helpful to you.

Sharing your research can also help you in the following ways:

- Searched using the wrong terms? If you post the search terms you used, someone can help you with better search terms.
- Spent a half hour on a website that had your answer, but you didn't see it? Someone familiar with the website can help.

Comment: This is saying why it's important to do research, but that's not the question, the question is *how much research should be done*.  This post doesn't answer that question.

Comment: No, but it addresses the implicit "why did I get a snarky response?" question, so it is useful even if slightly off-topic ...

Comment: I think that the power behind this answer is not obvious, and I think that it is very on topic.  I can't count the number of times I have started writing a question, and by the time I was done researching and drafting the question, I had found a satisfactory answer.  I think that there is a lot of power in taking a perceived problem in your head and framing it in a way that you can explain it to someone else.

Comment: While I've only recently began posting regularly on SO, I will typically leave a comment asking if a user tried searching a specific phrase with a link to the Google search.  It's not meant to be snarky, instead, it's meant to be helpful.  When I started programming I used to ask my mentor twice a day, "What do I need to Google to figure this out?!?!?!" because I was searching the wrong terms.

Answer (score 53):

*It is not enough to do the research. You must also* ***show us*** *that you have done the research.*

Stating "I googled for hours and didn't find anything" is not satisfactory mostly because "finding nothing" is completely impossible. Typing a single search phrase in Google will get you millions of hits, which is far from "didn't find anything".

To start, tell us what search terms you used. Then we can help you with better search terms, including the exact terminology which is unfamiliar to you.

Maybe you found a page that was related to your search term, but you were unable to see how you can adapt it to your situation. Provide a link and we can help you decipher it.

Ultimately, you need to demonstrate the effort you have put in.

Comment: I broadly agree. I would note, however, that too many details of how you attempted to solve the problem can result in an overly long difficult to read questions. I've had people say questions aren't clear precisely because I've tried to include as many details as possible. I hypothesis there is also an effect where people don't want to answer questions which include a lot of attempts to solve a problem.  Also the more your write, the less well proof-read it will be. Perhaps it's better sometimes to just ask a *simple* question, and deal with the obvious comments rather than to pre-empt them.

Comment: @AttRigh Yes, getting the right amount of information in a question is a delicate balance. This balance is similar to the tension between "minimal" and "complete" in an MCVE. One of my favorite quotes from Albert Einstein applies: "Keep it as simple as possible but no simpler."

Comment: *"finding nothing" is completely impossible* is probably right. But I remember a time where Google wasn't smart enough to handle "R" (programming language) correctly and showed results of topic "wo**r**d" instead. The results algorithm is a black box and especially this search engine uses all gettable data from a user to detect what user wants to search. This leads to many false postives in recall due to historical data if user wants to find documents of ambigous words (e. g. latex). This could be very frustrating. Search terms could also lead to different results for different users, then.

Comment: @colidyre Good point. Ideally an OP would write something like "I searched google for 'R' and got many irrelevant results such as...". Of course, we live in a far from ideal world.

Comment: I disagree with this. When I research I try a lot of different web-sites and a lot of different search terms. If I were to post *all* that it would be noise. You should not have to read my thesis on a subject. You should show that you have made some effort though by demonstrating some key related knowledge.

Comment: @BruceAdams nothing in my answer says to write a thesis dissertation. I am only saying that stating "I searched the internet and found nothing" is insufficient. There is a lot of ground between these two extremes.

Comment: I absolutely agree its just the telling people the search terms you used that I took objection to. That's some appropriate but rarely.

Comment: Sometimes I have done more than 50 searches with various combinations of keywords until I find a specific combination that gives one web page that has the clue I need to figure it out.  So if I give up after 49 searches and post a question on SO am I really supposed to list all 49 searches with explanation of what they returned and why it wasn't what I wanted?  This is the red tape for why I do that 50th search and never post a question.  But it doesn't make SO the place to go to get answers - but it should be because the info is so hidden that if it were on SO people would be able to find it.

Comment: @JerryJeremiah "So if I give up after 49 searches and post a question on SO am I really supposed to list all 49 searches with explanation of what they returned and why it wasn't what I wanted?" Posting a summary that shows you have done some research is sufficient. Which of those 49 attempts seemed the most promising? Focus on those and we can point out what you missed or point you in the right direciton.

Comment: I heavily disagree with "_Stating "I googled for hours and didn't find anything" is not satisfactory mostly because "finding nothing" is completely impossible. Typing a single search phrase in Google will get you millions of hits, which is far from "didn't find anything"._" ---> so you expect someone to look through 1 million results?

Comment: @10Rep "so you expect someone to look through 1 million results?" No. My point is that the statement "I googled for hours and didn't find anything" is demonstrably false. There are many more options than "didn't find anything" and "look through all million results". When you ask a question, you should demonstrate that you did the work by explaining what you found and why it doesn't solve your problem.

Comment: It's easy to do the research, but it's more difficult to present the research if part of it answers some other question or there is some element of overlap.  The hard part is not putting so much effort that you're offended when the initial reaction of the community to your question is negative.

Comment: I can show you PLENTY of cases where the person shows the research, includes minimal, reproducible code, and yet, the question gets downvoted for no good reason. The truth is that the Stack Overflow has gotten this reputation of being extremely toxic for a reason. I used SO for a few years before I opened an account, and I remember back then, people were not as quick to downvote questions and answer. I have gone to check some of the questions and answers some of these downvoters posted in the past and it is hilarious to see the quality of some of those posted (let's say) 10 years ago.

Comment: @user56983 I agree. Showing what you found in doing research and what you tried based on that research is non-trivial. As a frequent answerer, it is frustrating how little effort some posters put into even trying.

Answer (score 38):

Some people neglected the necessary learning process when approaching new things. I think it is important to point out that, when talking about *research* your question, **research doesn't just mean search**. Yes I agree it is a correct attitude to ask when you don't know. But it does not imply that one should ask whenever they come across something they don't know.

SO is not a site meant for those who skip the first 4 chapters of a tutorial or a book. There are plenty of tutorials, documentation and blog articles about virtually any topic one can think of. Is it really a problem that requires explanation or is the person just lazy to read? This is often a basis for my up-vote or down-vote.

The only type of *new* questions I can think of, is either an application that requires non-conventional decisions to be made, or a question about new technology (say HTTP v3 is released yesterday).

Comment: on the other hand, writing *tomes* about things have become the intimidating justification of *"value"*. On the top of that, we all may know there are industries built on making patents and some specifications deliberately long, obfuscated and hard to understand, an immoral way of protecting interests. Being succinct and concise while remaining understandable is very hard but it gives even more value to a work. In a quote attributed to Pascal, `I didn't have time to write a short letter, so I wrote a long one instead.`

Comment: *"There are plenty of tutorials, documentation and blog articles about virtually any topic one can think of"* I agree, but note that stack overflow does quite a good job of "indexing" them.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/299049/is-stack-overflow-only-for-professionals?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: In fairness, I have found myself asking a "Is it possible to..." or "Does anyone know a means to..." question on more than one occasion where the answer ultimately proves to be "No." Simple as that. How does one prove adequate research as been conducted when the desired outcome is a literal impossibility? Tricky to prove a negative, is all I'm saying. The corollary is also true: I've answered questions where the first half dozen answers are "Nope! Impossible!" but I have a means to perform the desired operation anyway. Is it not fair to think people are ASKING because they DON'T KNOW?

Comment: @NerdyDeeds These questions also tend to get deleted, because the impossibility is obvious to those with more background knowledge. It's a shame, because figuring out what is impossible and why is a great way to dive deeper into technologies.

Answer (score 33):

As a newbie here - and to programming in general - I do respect the need to do as much as you can before posting a question.

However, depending on your experience, you may reach a point of "I'm well and truly stuck" before an expert would. I sometimes tutor in math - and what's obvious to me sometimes isn't to someone else. That's not often a lack of effort on their part - it's that the resources they've used aren't speaking to them in a way they understand. Sometimes you have to take time to walk someone through things in more than one way.

It's a matter of opinion, I guess, but I like being able to help someone who has tried something, but just can't quite get it or is missing something. It's part of learning - asking questions (other than "do this for me") is good.

If this were strictly a professional site, then I could see wanting to turf the amateur questions. But coming as an amateur, I like the idea of my questions being addressed, in order to help me learn.

Comment: I think the point isn't that beginner questions are a problem. It's that question without effort of the person asking are. I'll upvote a question that has good research and a nice little example, even if it's just due to misreading the manual. Heck, I've asked such questions myself...

Answer (score 26):

How much research should you do? Well, we can never known *how much* research you have *actually* done, because we have not been observing you, and we can not evaluate the truth of a claim by you that you have "searched for ages".

And the truth is, we don't **really** care how much research you do. Because this site is not *about you specifically* and not about *you doing work*. The site is for *professional and enthusiast programmers* and intends to build a *useful repository* of *high quality* questions and answers by having experts answer questions for free. If someone criticises your question because "you have not done enough research", what they *really* mean is that the you have not done the research expected of a professional or enthusiast and that would result in a useful high-quality question. So instead, consider how a lack of research can be incompatible with that purpose.

- If the programming language, programming library or API your question is about has readily available (which means, on the Web), clear and complete documentation, a professional is expected to read that for answers, and an enthusiast is expected to be *happy* to read it. An answer that simply points you to that official documentation and quotes the relevant part of it is not a *useful* answer: it simply duplicates what is available elsewhere. If your question can be answered like that, you have not done enough research. However, if the official documentation is incomplete, or unclear, or out of date, an answer that points you towards the official documentation *and* supplements that with corrections, explanations of difficult parts, and cross references to other relevant information *is* useful. You can imagine that someone else could also benefit from that supplementary information.
- If someone is looking for information, having that information scattered across multiple places in slightly different forms, of varying quality, is not useful: it is impractical to read it all, but if you don't read it all, you might miss something important. It is much more *useful* to have **one** location containing the information needed in high quality form. We therefore do not want to have duplicate questions and answers. If this **site** *already* has a question similar to yours, asking your question and getting answers to it is *not useful* to **other** people. Sure, *you* might be helped, but the duplication would, in the long term, make things worse for other people. So you must search *this* site for existing questions and answers that are relevant for your problem. If you find that this site does have similar questions, but they are *not* similar enough to help you, your question should include links to those other questions and you must explain in your question *how* your question differs from those other questions and *why* none of the answers provided for those other questions are useful to you.
- Despite how it might sometimes appear, this site is not a place to get free debugging help for *your* programming problems. You *can* ask for help with debugging programs. But the question, and its potential answers, must be in a form that will be useful for others. Other people will, of course, have their own, different, programs to debug; for your debugging question to be useful to them they must be able to recognize the similarity between your problem and their problem. This means you must have done enough research to eliminate distracting extraneous details and trivial errors.
- Remember, when you ask a question here you are asking an *expert stranger* to give *their* time to help you *for free*. You are not entitled to their help. As they are experts, and probably professionals, their time is probably much more valuable than yours. You must do research so you do not waste their time or abuse this generosity of strangers.
- The format of this site, and its use of volunteers, means it is not practical for conveying all kinds of knowledge. It works best for clear questions that are each about one thing and that have few correct answers, which are short and clear. All technical questions and answers assume some level of relevant background knowledge. Answers that assume little background knowledge must be longer. Therefore questions about fundamental principles and broad abstract concepts are unsuitable for this site. You therefore must do enough research to narrow your problem down to a question about one thing, and for you to understand the fundamental principles and broad abstract concepts underlying computer programming in general and your question in particular.

In summary: you have done enough research if you can reasonably imagine that someone *else* searching for an answer to *their* question would also benefit from the answer(s) to your question.

Comment: FWIW, I've never interpreted "enthusiast" as someone being "happy". Just as a level between amateur and professional… :)

Comment: @deceze While I agree in those words, I also think it does apply since an enthusiast has enthusiasm, which is a form of enjoyment, e.g. happiness. Though it's a bit weird to apply "happiness" directly to enthusiast rather than "enjoyment".

Comment: "You are not entitled to their help." I find that there's a big difference between users that don't help by not answering and users that will exploit their own reputation to  unreasonably belittle your efforts in an attempt to damage your reputation.

Comment: @user1329514 belittling other users is against the rules, and very uncommon. Perhaps you are misinterpreting actions.

Comment: Oftentimes I see clear, concise, useful questions that are not answered elsewhere downvoted with comments that say it is easy if you just read the manual. So I believe this answer is incorrect. "Do your research" is not about the quality of the question, it is about the ego of the downvoter.

Answer (score 5):

The truth is that Stack Overflow is the best source for answers to commonly asked questions about poorly documented software. The top-rated answers are always much better than the original documentation.

And let's be honest: most software documentation is poor. The conceit of "read the manual" is the fanciful notion that the manual is actually good. The manual is usually awful.  Even the manuals for popular software projects tend to be disjointed, jargon-filled tomes of incomplete answers. They often only make sense to users who already know how to use the software and just need a reference for fine details.

Most software is just a collection of arbitrary design choices made by a small team of peculiar people with a limited set of skills. Then the supplicants hold up the manual like a tablet from heaven and reject anybody who does not recite the catechism.

We really shouldn't delude ourselves into believing the documentation is good or even that the software makes sense.  At its best, Stack Overflow breaks through the dysfunction and provides clear, complete answers to specific, widely applicable questions.

I find it counter-productive to require users to demonstrate how much effort they put into researching the question. If they are still confused after expending a lot of effort, then they probably are not even capable of writing a concise summary of the things they have learned. Their attempted solutions are likely overly complicated. Having them list all of the things they do not understand is not going to help anyone.

But I find that even if the documentation is confusing, I can usually learn enough from reading it to ask a well-posed question.

The principal criterion should be the clarity and focus of the question (Is the question understandable, answerable, and specific?). The second criterion should be whether the question is of practical importance (will others find the answer useful, too?) The final criterion should be whether the same question has already been answered somewhere else. If it has, that is fine, just mark the question as a duplicate and provide a link to the answer. Problem solved.

If it is a clear, concise question of practical importance that has not been answered somewhere else already, then Stack Overflow ought to provide the answer. How much effort went into posing the question is completely irrelevant, especially if many others will have the same exact question.

Comment: No, Stack Overflow **users** provide clear, complete answers to specific, widely applicable questions; and thus, **they** get to decide whether a question gets closed or stays open. A rant about how modern software is terribly documented or not documented at all will not change this.

Comment: The call for research effort is not for the sake of research effort itself, but for the positive consequences of doing it in the first place. Creating _"a clear, concise question of practical importance that has not been answered somewhere else already"_ in this platform does require some. Also, I find the documentation on Rust more elegant than most, yet people sometimes still ask questions which are already pretty well answered by the [official book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book), or by the stdlib docs. Evidence shows that research effort is, and will continue to be, important.

Comment: @E_net4theflagger According to your own logic, if some writes "a clear, concise question of practical importance that has not been answered somewhere else already" that is proof that they did research. My point is that should be enough.

Comment: @oguzismail You seem to be the only person arguing that Stack Overflow users each should use their own personal, arbitrary criteria to determine whether a question is closed. But I think your view is nevertheless widely held, and explains the unfair and inconsistent moderation voting I see across the site.

Comment: My point is that it's easy to underestimate the amount of research needed. In fact, we believe that [most of questions are not of that kind](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252506/question-quality-is-dropping-on-stack-overflow).